# What is the difference between internal working of doubly linked list of LinkedList and arrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Manipulation with LinkedList is faster than ArrayList because it uses doubly linked list so no bit shifting is required in memory. But in case of ArrayList, If any element is removed from the array, all the bits are shifted in memory.

So, what is the internal mechanism by which linkedList achieve this advantage for data manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArrayList` uses an array to store the elements. So an array might have 4 elements like this

```
[1][2][3][4]
```

and removing the third element would leave

```
[1][2][empty][4]
```

which means the programmer would have to manually move the elements to get

```
[1][2][4]
```

But linked list uses pointers so in the above example, the second node (the one with the value 2) can just have its pointer updated to point to the node storing 4.

Comment: Linked list uses pointers and ArrayList works at the index basis. That why the shifting is required in ArrayList. Right?

Comment: Exactly. By the way if my answer was useful to you I would appreciate it if you marked it as an answer =)